# Regular expression for adding slashes to string, except first slash in that string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have string in PHP, like:

```
"%\u0410222\u0410\u0410%"
```

And I need to modify the string by adding slashes like:

```
"%\u0410222\\\\u0410\\\\u0410%"
```

(add 3 slashes for each slash in string, except first slash)
I want to use PHP preg_replace for this case, and how to write regular expression?

Comment: probably easier to do the 1->3 for all slashes, then do a 3->1 for the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex way:

```
$result = preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)|\A[^\\\]*\\\)[^\\\]*\\\\\K~', '\\\\\\\\\\', $txt);
```

Note that to figure a literal backslash in a single quoted pattern, you need to use at least 3 backslashes or 4 backslashes for disambiguation (in this case for example `\\\\\K`). With the nowdoc syntax, only two are needed as you can see in detailed version:

```
$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~          # pattern delimiter
(?:
    \G     # position after the previous match
    (?!\A) # not at the start of the string
  |           # OR
    \A     # start of the string
    [^\\]* # all that is not a slash
    \\     # a literal slash character
)
[^\\]* \\      
\K             # discard all on the left from the match result
~x
EOD;
```

Without regex:(maybe more efficient):

```
$chunks = explode('\\', $txt);
$first = array_shift($chunks);
$result = $first . '\\'. implode('\\\\\\\\', $chunks);
```